# Cannot find name error angular

Tags: angular, service

Hello I'm new to angular and I am facing an error of cannot find a name `Categories`. I have created a service to fetch the data for `*ngFor`.

Service -

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Categories } from '../data/categories';
import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/categorydata';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {

  constructor() { }

  getCategories(): Categories[] {
    return CATEGORIES;
  }
}
```

Category.ts file

```js
import { subCategory } from './subcategory';

export class Categories {
  id: number;
  categoryName: string;
  subcatName: subCategory[];
}
```

Categorydata.ts

```js
import { Categories } from './categories';

export const CATEGORIES: Categories[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    categoryName: 'jeans',
    subcatName: [
        { subcategory: 'example' },
    ],
  },
];
```

Categories.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesService } from '../services/categories.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss']
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  categoryList: Categories[];

  constructor(private categoryservice: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryList = this.categoryservice.getCategories();
  }
}
```

When I run ng serve. It is giving me an error

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Categories'.

For line in categories.component.ts -

```js
categoryList: Categories[];
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? It should detect mistakes like these.

Comment: sublime text. Can you please suggest a better IDE for coding angular

Comment: Sublime is just fine. You should install some plugins for TypeScript I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the type Categories like you did in your service class so you can use the type:

```js
import { Categories } from '../data/categories';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the Categories type in your file.

Try to add the following in categories.component.ts:

```
import { Categories } from '/path/to/categories'
```